# apply form data from Django website to .exe file to generate link

Tags: django

I have built a Django website to accept data submitted from a user input form (an e-book application website). Upon application by the user, I could see their application on the backstage of the website and approve their application. This website is used only for several people.

I want to add a function like this:

The users who have accounts on this website could submit a request to download the e-book, in which they should write the details (author, year.... ) of the e-book.

I have already made an .exe file, which could accept parameters (author, year...) to generate a .txt file (the e-book).  I want to create an auto parameter passing function in my Django website. when I approve the users' application for the e-books on my website, the parameters they entered should be passed to the .exe file  to generate the .txt file automatically and save this .txt file on the server.

At the same time, a link that is linked to the storage position of the .txt file should be shown to the user so they could download the .txt file generated.

I have tried to deploy my Django project to pythonanywhere, but it's a linux server and so the .exe file could not be run on it.

I have these 2 questions:

1. Are there any free Windows server options to deploy my Django website to so that I could let the .exe file run in the backstage?
2. How to achieve the functionality of passing the parameters that the user entered to the .exe file automatically and show the link to the user for downloading (I have finished all the other functionality of the website, including storing the parameters they entered to the sqlite database)?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Honestly; the first paragraphs read well, but I have *no* clue what you are trying to express with your last statements. Please try to improve your content!

Comment: I don't know about number 1, but as far as number 2, I think you would need to generate a unique url that a user could go to, and then you would email the url to the user.  I would think that you would want to set a limit on how long the url is good for by recording the date/time it was created and then check that when a user visits the url.

Comment: @Dan Swain  Thanks. You are right. But how to achieve that, could you give some detailed suggestion please、